# An example Markov Decision Process model on setting rewards in a text sentence?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm looking to build a MDP and a reinforcement program in Python which works on generating text based on reward points in training data which is text sentences. I could not find any basic example program models which gives idea on how to build MDP on text sentences training data or identify which reinforcement model to use to generate texts. Can you please provide some suggestions / advice.

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Comment: For inspiration, you might want to see how hidden Markov models have been used in text generation. A quick came up with [this](http://www.wseas.us/e-library/conferences/skiathos2002/papers/447-308.pdf).